# Form back-end invalidation feedback - don't show again until next submit

Tags: javascript, reactjs, validation, state, formik

I have a Formik form on a page which when submitted, some fields may be invalidated by the back-end.

I keep track of the invalid values with Redux and dynamically update the validation schema for those fields (that might be a better way to do this but it's not the main point of this question, although this hypothetical better way might help me solve this problem)

In this form there are `ErrorMessage` components for the Input field elements and also a `MainErrorMessage`, above all fields in the form.

The ErrorMessage elements (specific to each input) will be displayed whenever a field value is invalid and that's all good.

**The problem:**

I want the `MainErrorMessage` to be displayed only after the form is submitted and invalidated by the back-end. Plus, I want it to *not* be displayed after the user dismisses it, or after it dismisses itself (for instance, when the user modifies the value of the input and it becomes valid), even if the input values become invalid again (the `ErrorMessage` components for the specific input fields will always display when they're invalid and that should be enough). Finally, I only want the `MainErrorMessage` to be displayed again when the form is submitted and invalidated by the back-end *again*.

In other words:

1. user submits form
2. server responds with error (eg: username is already taken)
3. `MainErrorMessage` is displayed (and also the input's `ErrorMessage`)
4. user changes the value (to a valid one). Both `MainErrorMessage` and `ErrorMessage` are gone.
5. user changes the value again (to an invalid one), and the `MainErrorMessage` is displayed again: *how can I prevent that? The `MainErrorMessage` should only be displayed again after another error response from the server.*

The best I could come up with looks crap and doesn't even work:

```
{shouldShowErrorNotification &&
  <>
    <Notification
      title={text.genericFormValidationErrorNotificationTitle}
      body={text.genericFormValidationErrorNotificationBody}
      type='error'
      dismissable={true}
    />
    {shouldShowErrorNotification = false}
  </>
}
```

So, `shouldShowErrorNotification` is a variable hanging just *outside* my functional component (which holds the form). I set it to true on formSubmit, and set it to false when the Notification appears (inside that block). But then the notification disappears (why?).

How to do this in a way that's more declarative?

Comment: your notification disappears because you reset it to false which forces React component to re-render. Do you know what to do with the error, what sort of error is coming back from server like username already taken and you want to prevent user from resubmitting using the same username? May be you just want to keep updating all the username taken and disallow user to submit all prior that they tried, is that your scenario? (Or in similar lines?) If so I may be able to help out on it